# Thousand separator with commas and decimal with dots on django template

Tags: django, templates, format

I don't if it's possible to format some value with that specific way. I know that if I use {{value|intcomma}} I get some like: 1.500 but my problem is that I want something like this: $1,500.50. I don't if I can do it on my template. This is part of my code:

```
{% load humanize %}    
{% for subservicio_sel in total_subservicios|servicios_adicionales:servicio_sel %}
     <li>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <p>{{subservicio_sel.Servicio_Adicional.Nombre}}</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
        <p>${{subservicio_sel.Servicio_Adicional.Precio|intcomma}}</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you have localization enabled in the settings try disabling it: ``USE_L10N = False``. For latin america the format is usually ``1.500,00``

Comment: Thanks, this work but it shows me only dots for decimals, I can't see the comma for thousands

Comment: Add ``USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True`` to your settings.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link might be of some help. adding THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True in settings.py

The link also has a bunch of number grouping options.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-THOUSAND_SEPARATOR

Comment: I have to say, I also had to disable: USE_L10N = False. As Pedro said.

Comment: Yeah it says to do that in the document, my apologizes for not adding that i my answer

Comment: @Antimada it's USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True and not THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True